# serching into a really big list from another bigger list in R

Tags: r

im working on tensroflow CNN and i need to change the names of a set of pictures, supose i have three lists

```
filename <- c("1.jpg", "2.jpg" "3.jpg", ...., )
name <- c("a", "b", "c", "c", "a", "b",....,)
name_idx <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", ..., )
```

the length of filename and name are the same(name is the person who is on the picture) i want to create another list, say

```
new_name <- matrix(0,length(name), 1)
```

which will contain the new name of the picture, the first entry would be a.1.jpg and the 5th would be a.2.jpg, the 4th would be c.2.jpg and so on

now i have this code

```
contador <- matrix(0,length(name), 1)
for (j in 1:length(name_idx)){
k <- 0
for (i in 1:length(name)){
if (name[i] == name_idx[j]){
k <- k +1
contador[i] <- k
}
}
}

for (i in 1:length(name)){
paste0(name[i], ".", contador[i], ".jpg")
}
```

it does the work very well when the size of the vectors are... relatively small the problem is that im working with a length(filename) = 1.4 million
and the length of name_idx is about 350,000. i ran this code like the last Thursday, today is monday and it has not finished yet jeje, do you know a better(faster) way to acomplish this? i would be so tank to you people if you can helpme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed tricky. One solution would be to generate increasing sequences of integers for each one of the levels in the vector `name`. For this, the function `ave` is perfect.

On the example,

```
paste0(name, ".", ave(name, name, FUN = seq_along), ".jpg")
```

Gives the result

```
[1] "a.1.jpg" "b.1.jpg" "c.1.jpg" "c.2.jpg" "a.2.jpg" "b.2.jpg"
```

---

Comparison to the double for loop solution.

```
f1 <- function(name) {
  name_idx <- unique(name)
  res <- rep(NA, length(name))
  contador <- matrix(0,length(name), 1)
  for (j in 1:length(name_idx)){
    k <- 0
    for (i in 1:length(name)){
      if (name[i] == name_idx[j]){
        k <- k +1
        contador[i] <- k
      }
    }
  }
  for (i in 1:length(name)){
    res[i] <- paste0(name[i], ".", contador[i], ".jpg")
  }
  return(res)
}

f2 <- function(name) {
  paste0(name, ".", ave(name, name, FUN = seq_along), ".jpg")
}

library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)

randomnames <- sample(letters, 100, replace = TRUE)

mb <- microbenchmark(f1(randomnames), f2(randomnames), times = 1000)
autoplot(mb)
```

This gives the following result.

[image: Comparison]

Comment: this looks great! but one question, this would be faster that the doble for method?

Comment: It should be faster, I'm not sure how it behaves on really big vectors, though.

Comment: hey bro ssry for bothering you, but i get this error, perhaps you can giveme some light on this Error in x[...] <- m : replacement has length zero